# checkedbox found uncheck on previous page after clicking on next page

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, gridview

when i checked [checked box] data on my page (1) and then go on to next page (2) through paging(bottom button of pages like [1234]) and then checked data on page (2).

when i came back to page (1) then it remain unchecked as i don't checked anything!!!

all the things remains at its original positions. all are unchecked on both pages .
when coming from 1 page to page 2 (check-boxes of page 1 forget his value and get unchecked) and after when coming from page 2 to page 1 same thing happens.
sorry for my bad and rough English.
any suggestion??

Comment: paging,are you using some repeater controls?please paste your PageIndexChanging code here

Comment: bro i have to much code to review but it will help me to understand u....check this plz

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow pop in ListerGrid.Rows)
            {

                CheckBox chkPop = (CheckBox)pop.FindControl("chkPop");
                if (chkPop.Checked)
                { 
                    NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();

                    string strPOP = ((Label)pop.FindControl("lblPOP")).Text;
                    DataTable td  = spp_db.getPop(ddlSelCat.SelectedValue,ddlSection.SelectedValue,ddlPJP_DSR.SelectedValue,
                             ddlTown.SelectedValue,ddlLocality.SelectedValue,ddlSubLocality.SelectedValue,strPOP);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If its a gridview or any repeater control try this

Gridview HTML

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="True"  
PageSize="5" Width="324px" DataKeyNames="CategoryID" 
OnPageIndexChanging="GridView1_PageIndexChanging">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryID" HeaderText="CategoryID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="CategoryName" />
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

CS Codes

```
protected void GridView1_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
  RememberOldValues();
  GridView1.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
  BindData();
  RePopulateValues();
}
```

And

```
private void RememberOldValues()
{
  ArrayList categoryIDList = new ArrayList();
  int index = -1;
  foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
  {
   index = (int) GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
   bool result = ((CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1")).Checked;

  // Check in the Session
  if (Session[CHECKED_ITEMS] != null)
   categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session[CHECKED_ITEMS];
  if (result)
  {
  if (!categoryIDList.Contains(index))
   categoryIDList.Add(index);
  }
  else
   categoryIDList.Remove(index);
  }
  if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
   Session[CHECKED_ITEMS] = categoryIDList;
}
```

And

```
private void RePopulateValues()
{
  ArrayList categoryIDList = (ArrayList)Session[CHECKED_ITEMS];
  if (categoryIDList != null && categoryIDList.Count > 0)
  {
  foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
  {
   int index = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
  if (categoryIDList.Contains(index))
  {
   CheckBox myCheckBox = (CheckBox) row.FindControl("CheckBox1");
   myCheckBox.Checked = true;
  }
  }
  }
}
```

Bind Data Code

**EDIT**

```
/* QUERY */
private const string QUERY_SELECT_ALL_CATEGORIES = "SELECT * FROM Categories";

private void BindData()
{
  SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
  SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(QUERY_SELECT_ALL_CATEGORIES,
  myConnection);
  DataSet ds = new DataSet();
  ad.Fill(ds, "Categories");
  GridView1.DataSource = ds;
  GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

For more details chk this [Maintaining_State_of_CheckBoxes](http://aspalliance.com/774_Maintaining_State_of_CheckBoxes_While_Paging_in_a_GridView_Control.all)

Comment: Oh,I forgot to put the query variable look above the BindData() function above

Comment: hey sajan. now i have new problem , i have implemented all the provided code to my code. now it does not go on next page. when i click page2 then it remains on page 1 . and nothing happens!!!

Comment: and hence the work resolved man.............thanks alooooot for your help.......v v thankhs mannnnnnn.......!!!!

Answer (score 0):

When you are navigating from one page to another ,your page refreshes so it cant retain value for checkbox,If you want to do this you have to do it from code behind ,write code 
Checkbox.Checked=True in !IsPostback according to your valid conditions.

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow pop in ListerGrid.Rows)
            {

                CheckBox chkPop = (CheckBox)pop.FindControl("chkPop");
                if (chkPop.Checked)
                { 
                    NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();

                    string strPOP = ((Label)pop.FindControl("lblPOP")).Text;
                    DataTable td  = spp_db.getPop(ddlSelCat.SelectedValue,ddlSection.SelectedValue,ddlPJP_DSR.SelectedValue,
                             ddlTown.SelectedValue,ddlLocality.SelectedValue,ddlSubLocality.SelectedValue,strPOP);